# Opening a page when user clicks on a toast notification

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-runtime, azure-storage

i am sending a toast from Azure to my Win 8 App whenever there is an successful insert operation into the table .
Here is the script

```
request.execute({
        success: function() {
            // Write to the response and then send the notification in the background
            request.respond();
            push.wns.sendToastImageAndText02(item.channel, {
                text1:' Blue Flame Detected !',text2 :'Please Click on the message for Instruction Set',Duration:'ToastDuration.Long',sound:'reminder',image1src:item.imageUri
            }, {
                success: function(pushResponse) {
                    console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I would like the toast to open a new page in my application when user clicks on it. I know toast has Activated event but how can i use it from my Azure script?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `launch` parameter in toast notification. Here's example of toast notification in Windows Store App, but you can use the same scenario in Windows Azure push notification service.

[How to pass arguments to an app activated by a toast notification](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-app-activated-by-a-toast-notification/)

[How to handle activation from a toast notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761468.aspx)